# Flutter: How to Detect lock/unlock state event in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, events, mobile

Hello I have a query while detecting lock/unlock state for ios i have used `screen_state` plugin which only support android but not ios so can anyone tell me how can i detect in flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/screen_state

> Note: I want device lock unlock status not pause, active, inactive status because flutter provides `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` i don't want to use that because it do not differentiate between real lock event with app minimize.

Comment: > is_lock_screen Can it solve the problem you need? https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen

Comment: No not at all i think the one who created this plugin don't know the difference between screen lock and screen inactive as you can see in its readme it print message on screen inactive which means when device lock it also print same and app minimized it also print same